# Import secret keys into gpg is imported but not really?

Tags: gnupg, secret-key

I would like to import my secret key from another laptop so I did :

```
$ gpg2 --allow-secret-key-import --import /mnt/very-secret/private/keys/my-precious.asc
gpg: key 51D5DF*********: "John Doe <john.doe@acme.com>" not changed
gpg: key 51D5DF*********: secret key imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
gpg:       secret keys read: 1
gpg:  secret keys unchanged: 1
```

But later on I did :

```
$ gpg2 --list-secret-keys | grep 51D5DF
```

And I don't see my secret key. I don't understand why it isn't visible with the `--list-secret-keys` option.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this one?   Same problem, linux and windows.

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue. GnuPG 2.2.27, Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. Could you provide more details?